# Is there an in-universe explanation for why Transformers suddenly started using guns instead of transformed parts of their bodies?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

In the first 2 films the Transformers transformed parts of their bodies into guns (for example, Bumblebee and Ironhide are seen in closeups doing that. Also the cube-infected items do that). In the 3rd and 4th films, all of a sudden, they use handheld guns and swords (in 4 we see them running out of ammunition for the first time, even) instead of transforming parts of their bodies like in the first two films.

Is there any in universe explanation for this (aside from the script writers suddenly finding hand held guns and swords cooler after 2 films not using them)?

Comment: Because kaboom! kapow! Look at all the explosions! Ooh, Shiny!

Comment: Micheal Bay caring about a cohesive, properly constructed universe? Nah. What @Richard said, pretty much.

Comment: That is why I asked if there is any IN universe explanation. out of universe.......the writers did a horrible job in terms of consistency (even more so when it comes to characters staying in character......only say bumble bee and the other autobots behaving like decepticons....or when they want to kill a guy at all costs then "you are old scrapmetal now" -uhm ok taht was bad we are we are going now and pout-)

Comment: And out of universe its clear that they thought with part 3+ that hand held weapons are way cooler now.

Comment: @Richard I read that in Warpath's voice.

Comment: Running out of ammo seems like a good reason to switch to swords.

Comment: Where the swords in the first two films were transformed out of their hands and 3+ were hand held weapons

Comment: Because, Michael Bay

Comment: @Robert That's the out-of-universe answer :P Richard gave the same, of course, but the in-universe variant, which was specifically asked for. :D

Comment: @BMWurm, I know :), just giving you a hard time.

Comment: The NRA complained that it gave kids the wrong idea about not having to pay for ammo

Answer (score 9):

> **Out-of-Universe**

After the negative outcry following Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen, there were several minor creative differences introduced in the third film. Some of these differences were in how the Transformers looked & acted. For instance, many of the racial stereotypes depicted in "Revenge of the Fallen" were toned down considerably for "Dark of the Moon." In addition, several attempts were made to give Decepticon characters additional dialogue & personality. This trend continued with "Age of Extinction", with both Optimus Prime's original truck form (albeit white) and the Dinobots being added largely as fan service.

It's likely that the switch from "home-grown" weapons to actual weapons was simply one of these changes, perhaps in a bid to bring it closer to the source material.

> **In-Universe**

The most reasonable in-universe explanation is that the new weapons were designed by (or with the assistance of) the NEST Team scientists. It's shown that NEST has begun experimenting heavily with Cybertronian technology during the three years between "Revenge of the Fallen" and "Dark Side of the Moon", along with help from the Autobots. It's highly likely that the weapons seen in use by the Transformers were, in fact, a product of these joint efforts.

Comment: Although nest seems to have used only human made weapons with the exceptions of those handed to them during the final battle by the autobot scientist. Aside from that autobots seemed very very cautious in giving out technology (even during transformers 2 already)

Answer (score 3):

I can't see there being any possible in-universe reason otherwise I'm sure it would have been mentioned in the films. Then again, it is Michael Bay...

I think this change was made due to artistic license and the need to create dramatic effect by "running out of ammunition".

Comment: Although that need only came up once in transformers 4 and not in 3 where it was introduced. there it was interestingly even a mix sometimes between the two types (inbuilt and handheld)

Answer (score -2):

I would say perhaps the in built guns took energon supply or somehow the transformers manufacture ammunition for the inbuilt guns in them, and using it takes on their supply of energy or internal metal maybe

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is there there any evidence to support this answer though, or is it just a guess? A good answer should be based at least partially on known facts, not pure speculation.